# Minimize Simple Function Using Rglpk

Tags: r, matrix, optimization, linear-algebra, minimize

I took linear algebra in college 5+ years ago, and I've forgotten most things. Thus, I'm looking for math help as well as R help.

I have the following matrices:

```
A <- matrix(c(0,0,0), nrow=1) 
B <- t(matrix(c(3,1,2,2,3,1,1,3,2), nrow=3)) 
C <- matrix(c(10, 15, 5), nrow=1) 
D <- matrix(c(1,1,1), nrow=3)
```

I want to minimize the following equation by manipulating the values of A

```
( ( A %*% B ) - C ) %*% D
```

My maximum and minimum constraints for A are the following:

```
max <- matrix(c(2,4,6), nrow=1)
min <- matrix(c(.5,1,1.5), nrow=1)
```

Right now, if I use Excel Solver with the same parameters, the minimized output is 2.6667, with a solution of

```
A = [0.5  3.3333  1.5]
```

I looked up other examples where people used the package **Rglpk**, but couldn't quite figure out how to configure my pieces to work with *Rglpk_solve_LP*.

I appreciate any help on this!